# SQL If syntax error

Tags: sql, if-statement, syntax

I have lil - one sql stuck error (1064).

```
SELECT sum(if(d.o_amount<='10')) as ten_s
```

I know we have here simple syntax error, but how i can fix it?
Thanx!

Comment: There is no `if` statement in SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if condition is true then what you have to do??? that you not write

Comment: Use `CASE` or `IIF` but it is - most of the time - better to do such things in `WHERE` or `HAVING` . Read about *set-based* thinking vs. procedural or *row-based* approaches

Comment: Short explanation: Just imagine a table with millions of rows and just a few of them fit to your filter. If you use a `WHERE` to pick the fitting rows and do the `SUM` just with them (even better with an index!) it will be fast. Going through all rows and doing a SUM with condition will need to run through the whole set...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean:

`SELECT sum(d.o_amount) as ten_s FROM table_name WHERE d.o_amount <= 10`

Comment: Somewhere should be a FROM, but +1 for your guessing abilities :-)

Comment: Thx, added the from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d.o_amount<=10 THEN d.o_amount ELSE 0 END) as ten_s
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use a `CASE` expression. Just an other perspective.

**Query**

```
select sum(case when d.o_amount <= 10 then d.o_amount else 0 end) as ten_s
from your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the rest of your query:

you can just add a restriction on amount value:

```
SELECT sum(d.o_amount) as ten_s 
FROM table_name 
WHERE d.o_amount <= 10
```

Or use a `case` expression to keep all rows but only sum thoses you need:

```
SELECT sum(case when d.o_amount <= 10 then d.o_amount else 0 end) as ten_s
```